# MATLAB: IIR Filter coefficients

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, numerical-methods

I am fairly new in signal processing, and one of my projects is to implement a C++ filter class. I need the  higher order coefficients of typical filters such as Chebyshev types I and II, Butterworth, Elliptic, and unfortunately, most of the coefficient tables in the net only lists up to 10th order max. I decided to use MATLAB to generate these filters and get their higher order coefficients, however one thing that I'm confused about is that they only give out 1 set of coefficients, which I assume to be analogous to saying (ao,a1,a2.....an).

I learned that IIR filters have 2 sets of coefficients, usually expressed as a0,a1...an and b0,b1,...,bn. Here is my MATLAB code to generate these coefs and export them to an excel file:

```
 %Chebyshev Filter Coefficients

 filename = 'cheby2coefs.xlsx';
 for Order = 1:64 
 fprintf('This is');
 disp(Order);
 fprintf('coefficients');
 [i,j] = cheby2(Order, 20, 300/500);
 disp([i,j]);
 fprintf('\n');

  xlswrite(filename,[i,j]',Order);
end
```

So far there has been little sources on the net on how to come up with these coefficients with MATLAB, so I'm having a hard time. My question is that, how exactly does one produce the IIR coefficients for these filters (Assuming they're IIR)?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @EitanT Edited my post, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track. Your call to `cheby2` is missing the `Wst` parameter (the stopband frequency). You should read [MATLAB's official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cheby2.html) for this command and verify your call.

Also, don't name the output variables `i` and `j`, it's bad practice. `i` and `j` are reserved names for the `sqrt(-1)` imaginary number. Name the output variables `b` and `a` at least.

Once you're done with Chebyshev, use [`butter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html) and [`ellip`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/ellip.html) for the Butterworth and elliptic filters, respectively.

Comment: Thanks! And will do about the variable conventions. I'm a bit concerned with the outputted coefficients. As I've said in my post, IIR filters should have 2 sets of coefficients per order, this one just generates 1 set of numbers. Is there something I'm missing entirely?

Comment: `b` is one set of coefficients (in the numerator of the transfer function), and `a` is the second set of coefficients (in the denominator of the transfer function). Note that `a` and `b` are arrays (vectors).

Comment: I see! I never knew that, i thought [i,j] was the list of coefficients. If i and j are the coefficients, what's in [i,j] say, if you export it or display it in the cmd window?

Comment: That depends. `[i, j]` can have a different meaning. It usually means that you're trying to concatenate two vectors `i` and `j` horizontally. **However**, in your case, where it's on the left hand of an assignment, it means it's a list of output variables returned by a function.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir EitanT! I was having a bit of a problem finding out where the 2nd set of coefs are, and they were there all along!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be covered in the [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/cheby2.html):

> [b,a] = cheby2(n,R,Wst) designs an order n lowpass digital Chebyshev Type II filter with normalized stopband edge frequency Wst and stopband ripple R dB down from the peak passband value. It returns the filter coefficients in the length n+1 row vectors b and a, with coefficients in descending powers of z.